# Help with self-referencing model & view in Rails 3

Tags: model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, self-reference

I have a simple Client table (or model) where a Client can have a Parent Client (only one, or none). I modeled it this way:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Client', :foreign_key => 'parent_id’
end
```

That seems to work fine.  I have two questions:

1. **Is that the correct why to represent that relationship in an R3 model.**
2. **What should the _form.html.erb look like?** For example, I want a drop-down box listing all of the possible Clients (and None) as the Parent field.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to #2:

```
<div class="field">
   <%=f.label :parent %><br/>
   <%= collection_select(:client, :parent_id, Client.all, :id, :name, {:include_blank => true} ) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, number #1  is correct. Sorry, just realised how old this question is!